# Batch Processor copy after matching list

Tags: powershell, batch, processing

I have a list of string as under:

```
UMSADF984
ASDNM8313
JMKADUJ73
```

and I have folder which contains child folder with folder names as

```
19UMSADF984S2
18ASDNM8313S3
12JMKADUJ73SD
```

I want to make match both and copy the folders which have the string of table 1 in the folder name

Sorry I am a novice to Powershell or Batch processor. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Following might get you started

```
@('UMSADF984','ASDNM8313','JMKADUJ73') | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem -name "*$($_)*" } | 
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_ -Destination $env:temp\test\ -WhatIf}
```

Breakdown

```
@('UMSADF984','ASDNM8313','JMKADUJ73')     - a list of partial folder names
|                                          - pass through the pipeline
Foreach-Object { ... }                     - perform an action on each object
Get-ChildItem -name "*$($_)*"              - get all folders matching on wildcard
Copy-Item $_ -Destination $env:temp\test\  - copy the folder to your temp\test folder
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to run this as a Powershell or Batch script ?

Comment: This is a powershell script.